# Declaring variable above vs below @interface

Tags: objective-c

```
int helloness;
@interface test : NSObject
@end
```

vs

```
 @interface test : NSObject{
int helloness;
}
@end
```

Do I understand that following are true and the only meaningful differences between the above two blocks:

- in both blocks, the implementation of `test.m` can use `helloness` variable internally, like an ivar
- in the first block, `helloness` will exist for any class that imports this `.h` but is otherwise private only to `test.m` in the second block

In the first block, is this technically what is considered a "global variable" in that any class that imports this will have access to the same contents of `helloness`?

What happens if multiple header files have a declaration for `helloness` and you import them all?

Similar to this, consider this implementation:

```
 @implementation AClass

 int food=5;
```

Here, `food` acts like an internal iVar, even though it was not declared in any `@interface` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example, `helloness` is a global variable. It can be seen by any file which imports that header. If you include multiple headers which also declare an `int helloness` variable, I believe you'll get a warning from the compiler, and all of them will point at the same memory location. If you include another header which declares a `helloness` of type other than `int`, I believe you'll get a compiler error.

In the second example, `helloness` *is* an instance variable (ivar). Its value (memory location) is specific to each instance of `AClass`. (Anything can access it: e.g. `AClass *instance = [[AClass alloc] init]; instance->helloness = 7;` However, direct access to ivars is generally avoided in ObjC -- we use accessors and/or properties instead.)

In the third case, `food` is still a global variable, but its visibility is restricted to the implementation file it's declared in. Any instance of `AClass`, as well as any other classes or categories or functions implemented in the same file, can reference `food`, and all those references are to the same memory location.

Comment: in your third paragraph, is this the same as if i added `static` before it, in another words, a class variable?

Comment: Not quite -- I left something out. With `static`, it does behave like a "class variable": it's visible only to code in the same file. Without `static`, the declaration isn't visible to other files, but the *symbol* is... I think they can get at it using `extern`, and more importantly, you'll get linker errors if you have `food` in other files. (Global variables not declared `static` in an implementation file isn't something we see often, and probably for good reason.)

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, `helloness` is a global variable.  In your second example, it's an instance variable.

There can be only one global variable with a given name in your program.  There is a copy of an instance variable for each instance of your class that's created during your program's execution.  They're not semantically similar at all.

Having a global variable in a header file, as I presume you are doing in the first example since you refer to `#import`ing it, is probably a bad idea.  If it's not a tentative definition like yours is (for example if you instead had `int helloness = 12;`), you'll end up with multiply defined symbol errors at link time.

In your last example, `food` is still a global variable, but since it's likely to be in an implementation file (rather than a header), you probably won't run into any multiply defined symbol errors.  It *won't* work like an instance variable, though - it's still a global variable.

Comment: If a global variable is *not* in the header (as I think you suggest it should not be in the header), then how can another class access it? I tried moving it to the implementation but that only exposes it for that specific class.

Comment: The usual way for a compilation unit to refer to a global variable defined elsewhere is by using the `extern` keyword.

Comment: I tried putting `extern int helloness` and then i tried just `int helloness` either before or after the `@implementation` line in the `.m` but `helloness` is not exposed to any class that imports the `.h`

Comment: `extern` only makes sense for the global variable (i.e., the one declared *outside* of the `@interface` block in the header file. There's no reason to put `extern` in the implementation file.  Check out [this post](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/archives/840).

Comment: from what i gather from @rickster's answer, unless I declare in the header, I cannot expect any other class to access this global variable

Comment: That is pretty much true.  Strictly speaking, as long as you have `extern int helloness;` somewhere in each compilation unit, you should be fine.